# Kernel panic after using Android Emulator for Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, bug, shutdown, android, kernel-panic

I experienced a kernel panic.

1. When I run Android emulator on a MacBook, iMac, or Mac mini, I sometimes get a grey screen for unexpected shut down and instructions to press and hold the power button to restart the Mac.
2. After I upgraded to OS X Lion, only this grey screen came; it was working fine when I had Snow Leopard.
3. When I update software, the issue disappears for week or month but then it starts happening again.

Do I need to do something special to prevent these unexpected shut downs?

Should I downgrade it to Snow Leopard?

Or is it coming because I'd upgraded the same Lion install on 3 Macs? I've read somewhere that we can use OS X Lion on only five Macs.

Comment: Can you post the log from the kernel panic (/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports)

Comment: I've been updated my machine to Mountain Lion, will I get it now also there? As I am in office and here I don't have reports.

Comment: Did the workaround in my answer work? (Just out of curiosity)

Comment: No, I didn't check. I upvoted your answer while looking at your efforts in answering and btw I had upgraded my system to ML.

Comment: Why don't you? In the thread, people had reported a successful Android emulator on ML by editing eclipse.ini

Comment: For above comment, I left Android development and I am least interested in it. Thank you for giving your precious time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be, as you suspected, the Android emulator that is causing the issue.  Some users have filed [an issue on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19099).  If you scroll down past all of the "Me Too's," you'll actually find useful information; there appears to be a workaround involving `/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini` for some.

> I increased the heap space used by Eclipse, and haven't experienced this problem since.
>
> In eclipse.ini I used the following values:
>
> ```
> --launcher.XXMaxPermSize256m
>
> -Xms256m
>
> -Xmx1024m
> ```

The same issue has a [duplicate](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15025). In this thread, they mentioned a slightly different method where they added `-vmargs` between `--launcher.XXMaxPermSize256m` and `-Xms256m`

And I assume you've installed [Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager/), as this is a requirement for  the Android Emulator.  However, in the comments, people note that it doesn't work with Mountain Lion and they had to disable it for Android Emulator to work.

For your question about the number of installs Lion from the App Store will give you, this is directly from Apple's EULA (emphasis added):

> (i) to download, install, use and run for personal, non-commercial
>   use, one (1) copy of the Apple  Software directly **on *each*
>   Apple-branded computer running Mac OS X Snow Leopard or Mac OS X  Snow
>   Leopard Server (“Mac Computer”) that you own or control;**

So, assuming that this is for personal, non-commercial use, Apple lets you install Lion as many times as you like on the Macs that you own or control.